# How can I fade a View with a CAEAGLLayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I'm currently looking for a way to change the alpha value of a view with a CAEAGLLayer. Setting self.alpha doesn't work, so I think there must be some concept here I don't understand. The app I'm building has an opengl layer over live footage from the iPhone/iPod camera, and I'd like to fade this in and out. I've also tried setting the CAEAGLLayer's opaque and opacity value, which also won't work. Thanks for any thoughts you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to do something similar, i.e. have just the background of the CAEAGLLayer be transparent, so I can draw over a photo.  I have managed to fade the whole thing in and out setting the Alpha value on the layer itself in the layout editor of the Nib, which might work for you, but is not quite the effect I want.  What I really want is just a transparent background and there is discussion of how to achieve that here:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/20081-merging-content-uiimageview-eaglview.html

Although I haven't managed to get what they describe working yet ... :-(

Comment: Aha, and I just got my thing working, based on a tip here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283670/displaying-an-eaglview-with-transparent-background-on-a-uiimageview