# Displaying an EAGLView with transparent background on a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, 3d

I have an EAGLView displaying an OpenGL 3D model, and a UIImageView displaying an image.

What I want is to display EAGLView above that UIImageView with transparent background.

Is there any way to display this 3D model with transparent background, on top of the UIImageView.

Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

In EAGLView.m initialization

```
self.opaque = NO;
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
eaglLayer.opaque = NO;

CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
const CGFloat myColor[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
eaglLayer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreate(rgb, myColor);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);
```

Comment: That solves a different problem; that causes the EAGLView to be transparent. It shouldn't have any effect if the problem is that the UIImageView is on top of the EAGLView.

Comment: Actually I don't care about UIImageView, as I've mentioned above in question. Now I'm using a UIView under EAGLView. Making EAGLView transparent just gave me what I wanted. Underlaying components can be seen now. Thank you for sparing your time.

Comment: Your question says "What I want is to display EAGLView, above this UIImageView. No matter what I do, it keeps displaying UIImageView above EAGLView." but I don't see any point in squabbling about it. Glad you found an answer!

Comment: "You can use UIView if you want. Any solution would be appreciated." makes it flexible enough I think. Maybe next time I should be more clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

For reference, most of the accepted answer is unnecessary. The only key part is this (in the UIViewController - no need to edit or subclass EAGLView / GLKView):

```
self.view.opaque = NO; // NB: Apple DELETES THIS VALUE FROM NIB
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // Optional: you can do this in NIB instead
```

You can set the background Color in the NIB - but you CANNOT set the opacity (Apple seems to overwrite this var for GL views at initWithCoder :( )

Plus, of course, in your OpenGL code you need to clear to alpha=0.0. So, wherever your glClear / glClearColor calls are already, replace the clearColor with:

```
glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT for your answer. But what is the use of GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT in your last line ?

Comment: Unless you are doing some special effects, you have to clear the depth buffer every frame (along with your background colour) or else all your 3d positions will be wrong and things will render in the wrong order (or not at all)

Comment: Ah, ok. I have only 2 dimentions. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Often, even with 2 dimensions, you want to have "layers" of 2D content. In which case ... use the depth buffer, and you save yourself thousands of lines of custom code for maintaining your layering. Why do it in software when you have hardware waiting to do it for you? :)

Comment: NB: Apple DELETES THIS VALUE FROM NIB!?!?!?!?  I cannot stress the importance of this enough.  That was like an hour and a half of stuckness.

Answer (score 1):

UIView is the base class from which both EAGLView and UIImageView derive. As you are using EAGLView and UIImageView, you are using UIView.

UIViews have subviews. Probably you'll have a UIView for which both the UIImageView and the EAGLView are subviews. The normal rule is that subviews are drawn in the order in which they are listed. So if your UIImageView is being drawn on top of your EAGLView then it is later in the list.

If you're creating them and adding them as subviews programmatically, then do so in a different order, or switch from using [addSubview:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview%3a) to e.g. [insertSubview:belowSubview:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview%3abelowSubview%3a) for the UIImageView.

If you're laying things out in Interface Builder then just ensure the EAGLView is listed after the UIImageView.

Comment: I had tried using insertSubview:belowSubview before I sent this question. It couldn't solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Years late, but this work on iOS7 for me, [self.view.superview addSubview:imageview]; then send it to back.

Answer (score 1):

If u use GLKView all that need to do is

```
    view.opaque = NO;
    view.layer.opaque = NO;
    glClearColor(0.f,0.f,0.f,0.f);
```

Also for prepare displaying transparent texture

```
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

and if needed

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of above answers worked for me, I used this code modification to CCDirector.m and it worked ok:

```
-(void) setGLDefaultValues
{
    // This method SHOULD be called only after openGLView_ was initialized
    NSAssert( openGLView_, @"openGLView_ must be initialized");

    [self setAlphaBlending: YES];
    [self setDepthTest: YES];
    [self setProjection: projection_];

    // ***** NEW CODE: make open gl view transparent
    openGLView_.opaque = NO;
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    // ***** NEW CODE end

    // set other opengl default values
    //glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

#if CC_DIRECTOR_FAST_FPS
    if (!FPSLabel_) {
        CCTexture2DPixelFormat currentFormat = [CCTexture2D defaultAlphaPixelFormat];
        [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];
        FPSLabel_ = [[CCLabelAtlas labelWithString:@"00.0" charMapFile:@"fps_images.png" itemWidth:16 itemHeight:24 startCharMap:'.'] retain];
        [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:currentFormat];
    }
#endif  // CC_DIRECTOR_FAST_FPS

}
```