# Adding a CCLabel ontop of openGLView - cocos2d iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

So within a CCLayer I am adding an ImagePicker / Camera to the openGLView and then a UIButton - all good, but now I want to add a CCLabel (and in the future CCSprites) on top of those elements.

```
    uip = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    uip.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    uip.showsCameraControls = NO;
    uip.toolbarHidden = YES;
    uip.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    uip.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    uip.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(uip.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORM, CAMERA_TRANSFORM);

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:uip.view];

    arrowButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [arrowButton addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(arrowButtonClicked:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIImage *imgNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_next_norm.png"];
    [arrowButton setImage:imgNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIImage *imgPressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_next_pressed.png"];
    [arrowButton setImage:imgPressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    arrowButton.frame = CGRectMake(screenSize.width - 48.0, screenSize.height - 37.0, 48.0, 37.0);

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:arrowButton];

    CCLabelTTF* label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Experience 1" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:32];
    label.color = ccc3(0, 0, 0);
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    label.position = CGPointMake(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
   // [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:labe]; cant add to openGLView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to addSubview UIView components under the openGLView as the following,

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].superview addSubview:arrowButton];
```

And then, openGLView should be transparent. "[Displaying an EAGLView with transparent background on a UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283670/displaying-an-eaglview-with-transparent-background-on-a-uiimageview/5303578#5303578)"

**EDIT:**

> moving the Cocos on top of the UIImagePickerController

Ok, how about the following? addSubview the cocos2d view (openGLView) on cameraOverlayView of UIImagePickerController.

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].superview addSubview:uip.view];
[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] removeFromSuperview];
uip.cameraOverlayView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView];
```

Also, you need [Making Cocos2d Transparent](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1752).

Comment: Sorry, what I want is to show the label on top of the UIImagePickerController - moving the Cocos on top of the UIImagePickerController

Comment: Thanks for your help but its not showing up the Cocos elements - i have  [CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView.opaque = NO;
    
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  and added [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].superview addSubview:uip.view];
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] removeFromSuperview];
        [uip.cameraOverlayView addSubview:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]];

Comment: Please try to use glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) for sure that EAGLView is on cameraOverlayView. It should make the screen red.

Comment: it is not showing...I have tested that is it red by removing the camera, but it is not on top of the camera.

Comment: you think we have to move the position of openGLView for it to be viewed?

Comment: I misunderstood! How about "uip.cameraOverlayView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView];" !?

Comment: Great thanks, that adds it to the top, only thing now is that its not transparent...

Comment: How about "[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].opaque = NO;" ?

Comment: Did you change CC_DIRECTOR_INIT() in ccMacros.h? "pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8" is required for cocos2d transparent.

Comment: Kazuki, once I have closed the camera, how would add the openGLView again? I tried [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].superview addSubview:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]]; but its not working.

Comment: You must get the superview of openGLView for this situation before calling removeFromSuperview, like "superView_ = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].superview;", and then "[superView_ addSubview:[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView];"

Comment: UIView *superView_ = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].superview; uip.cameraOverlayView = nil; [uip.view removeFromSuperview]; [superView_ addSubview:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]]; is just removing everything.

Comment: Please get the superview before calling ANY removeFromSuperview for openGLView, just after CC_DIRECTOR_INIT() should be ok.

Comment: Ah so your saying have a reference to the super view and use that.