# Make an EAGLView transparent?

Tags: ios, transparent, eaglview

It's possible to place in a UIViewController object an EAGLView object and make the background of EAGLView transparent in order to view what is behind?

Thanks.

-UPDATE----

I've tried which appears in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283670/displaying-an-eaglview-with-transparent-background-on-a-uiimageview) post. But still the layer of the EAGLView appears like a black square. :(

Any idea why this is not working for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openGLView.opaque = NO`

Also pay attention on correct opacity in alpha channel of OpenGL framebuffer.
And pay attention on Tark answer about performance drop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an `EAGLView`, but it is definitely possible to have a [`CAEAGLLayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/QuartzCore/Reference/CAEAGLLayer_Class/CAEGLLayer/CAEGLLayer.html) with a transparent background on top of UIKit content. It is not recommended however, from the docs:

> Because an OpenGL ES rendering surface is presented to the user using Core Animation, any effects and animations you apply to the layer affect the 3D content you render. However, for best performance, do the following:
>
> - Set the layer’s opaque attribute to TRUE.
> - Set the layer bounds to match the dimensions of the display.
> - Make sure the layer is not transformed.
> - Avoid drawing other layers on top of the CAEAGLLayer object. If you must draw other, non OpenGL content, you might find the performance cost acceptable if you place transparent 2D content on top of the GL content and also make sure that the OpenGL content is opaque and not transformed.
> - When drawing landscape content on a portrait display, you should rotate the content yourself rather than using the CAEAGLLayer transform to rotate it.